# Extended consonant sounds in Korean

Tags: pronunciation

I noticed that many Korean speakers in order to emphasize some words tend to make the syllables longer and more intense (pretty much just like any other language). But this applies specially some to consonants sounds.

For example, the lady in this noodle commercial.

https://youtu.be/73IhaUwxKkw?t=194 at 3:16

Is there an specific name for this language phenomenon in the Korean Language?

Also, can someone please transcribe the woman lines in this part of the script?

Comment: In Korean, a vowel is always the core of a syllable, so the duration of vowel sounds must be extended as well. Technically, she blends an interjection (크으) and a syllable (큰) in the commercial rather than just extending the duration of the sound. [This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/59tyYMBRv2U?t=117) explains the interjection (He spells it as khhhhh, but Koreans spell it as 크, 크으, etc.).

Comment: "얼큰한 안성탕면 한 그릇 더 드시겠수?". Unfortunately I don't know how to translate "얼큰하다" in english; it is an adjective describing how the food(usually warm, somewhat hot soup) tastes. "안성탕면" is the name of the product. "한 그릇" is "a bowl", "더" is "more", and "드시겠수?" is "Would you eat/have?" with "eat" having the highest level of respect. Here "-겠수?" is a slightly less formal variation of "-겠소?" (or "-겠습니까?" if it sounds more familiar to you).